# Позиционирование элементов в Android

Tags: java, android

Помогите разобраться, не могу толком понять в расположение. Я задаю элементу во время движения конкретные координаты:

```
ObjectAnimator button_copy_button1 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(copy_pr1,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", 50),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("y", 1140));
```

На этих же координатах должен быть другой элемент. Как при создании этого элемента установить нужные координаты, в коде или xml?

```
                android:id="@+id/imv2"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/tamplateone"
```

Comment: new_view.setX/Y/Z

Comment: Это  работает, если мы помещаем на старте объект в точку 0.0 и только после запуска он уходит на заданные координаты. А как сразу задать нужные точки при создании?

Comment: да где вам будет угодно

Comment: Не совсем так. Попробую еще объяснить. Если я задаю координаты через .setX, то, например нужный мне параметр 50, 1140 выставиться только в том случае, если я размещу элемент изначально в базовую точку 0.0

Comment: Смотря какой родитель. У меня все работает

Comment: в каком У вас родителе используется? Я в КонстрейтЛайоут.

Comment: Relative Layout